# opennlp.groovy has NullPointerException

Tags: groovy, opennlp

I am trying to get the following code snippet from GitHub to work so that I can use OpenNLP tools in Groovy scripts.

(OpenNLP class from https://gist.github.com/nagaimasato/1178725)

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Grapes(
    @Grab(
      group='org.apache.opennlp',
      module='opennlp-tools',
      version='1.5.3'
    )
  )

import opennlp.tools.tokenize.*
import opennlp.tools.postag.*

OpenNLP nlp = new OpenNLP()

def tokens = nlp.workTokenize("Hello world")
println tokens

class OpenNLP {
    static TokenizerModel tokenizerModel
    static POSModel posModel
    static {
        def classLoader = OpenNLP.class.classLoader
        classLoader.getResource('opennlp/en-token.bin').withInputStream {
            tokenizerModel = new TokenizerModel(it)
        }
        classLoader.getResource('opennlp/en-pos-maxent.bin').withInputStream {
            posModel = new POSModel(it)
        }
    }

    Tokenizer tokenizer
    POSTagger tagger

    OpenNLP() {
        tokenizer = new TokenizerME(tokenizerModel)
        tagger = new POSTaggerME(posModel)
    }

    List workTokenize(String text) {
        return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    }

    List posTag(List tokens) {
        return [tokens, tagger.tag(tokens)].transpose() 
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I try to run the script:

```
Caught: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Greetings.class$(Greetings.groovy)
    at Greetings.$get$$class$OpenNLP(Greetings.groovy)
    at Greetings.run(Greetings.groovy:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method withInputStream() on null object
    at OpenNLP.<clinit>(Greetings.groovy:25)
    ... 3 more
```

I have en-token.bin and en-pos-maxent.bin in the right place for the script to find, but classLoader.getResource("opennlp/en-token.bin") is indeed null when I print it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if instead of the Grab, you put the required jars on the classpath by hand?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `en-token.bin` and `en-pos-maxent.bin` files are in a directory named `opennlp` and that the classpath includes the parent directory of `opennlp`.

Note that `./` is included in the classpath when you execute your Groovy script, so if you have your `opennlp` directory in the same directory as your Groovy script and you also invoke the Groovy script while you are in that directory, it should work (at least it worked for me). But if you execute the script while you are not currently in that directory (e.g. by using a path like `path/to/script.groovy`) it won't work. In that case, you can just invoke it using `groovy -cp path/to path/to/script.groovy`, thus putting the parent directory of your `opennlp` directory into the classpath manually.